# Resizing video for 3D

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

new in this forum and just approaching ffmpeg.
Try to explain my target:
In specific folder I have first play, intro, chapters menu and main videos (left and right eyes)
Videos are output in UHD (3840x2160), 95 Mb/s, 23,976 fps
I'd wish to know if there are a multiple commands in ffmpeg to get:
videos in HD (1920x1080), 25 Mb/s as max bitrate and 15 Mb/s as average bitrate, same framerate.
Obviously I'd like to loose  quality as less as possible (I know I will).
Just to be bit accurated:
I have UHD videos because I'll create HD, UHD and 3D videos.
Helps are very very appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Gio

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of ffmpeg? You should take a look at setting size and bitrates, codecs to use. Try this link first: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html. And yes there are a number of parameters and switches that are needed to get optimum results.

Comment: What's the reason for the specific bitrate requirements?

Comment: 3D speciments, overflow issues: I work with UHD with bitrate of approx 90\100 Mb/s, 3D needs HD video so I had to downscale size, extension (my authoring likes .mov) and, of course, bitrate. Tried with sw like TMPGEnc v7 but I can't apply all these in one time. you know:  a video manipulated several times, loose quality.......

Answer (score 0):

After googling and reading superuser posts, I've tried using this string:

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -preset slow  -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr" -b:v 15M -minrate 10M -maxrate 25M -bufsize 2M output.mov

This should:
- downscale UHD to HD
- create variable bitrate min 10Mb/s max 25 Mb/s
- change file from .mp4 to .mov

Any comments appreciated.

Gio